# Can't change text in textview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uitextview

I have problem with can't set new text in `UITextView` .I already link up the `IBOutlet` to `textView` in interface builder. Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Detail";
    [self setupTextView];

}

- (void) setupTextView
{
    self.textDescription = [[[UITextView alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSString *foo = @"blah blah blah";
    textDescription.text = foo; //I try this and it didn't work
    //here didn't work too.
    //textDescription.text = [textDescription.text stringByAppendingString:foo]; 

    /*Here is something for dynamic textview*/
    CGRect frame;
    frame = textDescription.frame;
    frame.size.height = [textDescription contentSize].height;
    textDescription.frame = frame;
     /**/
}
```

Thank you for anu help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.textDescription = [[[UITextView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

I think this is the problem. If `textDescription` is an `IBOutlet` you don't need to allocate it. Just remove this allocation.

Comment: Thank you.It's work I will accept ur ans in 2 min. (pop-up said that I can accept ans in 2 min.)